# Cannot connect Kafka running in docker

Tags: docker, apache-kafka

I have the below configuration in docker compose yml file for advertised listeners

My docker-compose.yml

```
  version: '2'
  services:
  zookeeper:
  image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
  network_mode: host
  environment:
  ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
  ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
extra_hosts:
  - "moby:127.0.0.1"

kafka:
image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
network_mode: host
depends_on:
  - zookeeper
environment:
  KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
  KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: localhost:32181
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://lnc52c9:29092
  KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
extra_hosts:
  - "moby:127.0.0.1"
```

and I connect this kafka using below property

```
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "lnc52c9:29092");
```

when I try to produce message in that server I am getting the below error

> WARN  o.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient - Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {foo=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}

The host is ping- able from my machine because its all in the same network ,no firewall issues. when I use the command `hostname` in the docker container I can see the same host name. Am I missing something?

Comment: Can you post your complete `docker-compose.yml`? Also where are you connecting to kafka from?

Comment: I have updated my full docker-compose.yml and I am using a virtual machine for this docker container ( https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-docker-images/blob/4.0.x/examples/kafka-single-node/docker-compose.yml ) . I am trying to connect this kafka from another windows machine where the host of docker container is pinggable , both are in same network.

Comment: What is the os of your VM?

Comment: Try to add this in your kafka service :

`KAFKA_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://0.0.0.0:29092`
If you use windows as VM host

Comment: The VM is redhat linux

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to [expose port](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) of kafka in the container. You can do this in docker-compose file, by adding something along the lines of:

```
ports: "29092:29092"
```

This should be in the kafka service definition.

Comment: Thank you but still i am getting that Leader Not Available error message

Comment: @adorearun Can you check if the port is open and you can connect to it? You can use a simple client like telnet: `telnet lnc52c9 29092` Do this from the docker containers and the other windows machine you really want to connect from.

Comment: `ports`not necessary when using `network_mode: host` - you could try to remove it and replace by `port` but it shouldn't change much
I also suspect some firewall/network issue - run also the telnet command from your VM. If it works on VM but not on other machine, and the machine is pingable, check your firewall policy